# Is the land on which the apartment building stands owned by the residents?

Tags: india, real-estate

This is about apartments in India. Let's say if an apartment building has 6 flats in it and all of them are bought. Do all the owners of these flats own the land on which this apartment building stands?

Let's say couple of scenarios:

- There was an earthquake and the building gets damaged and becomes uninhabitable. In this case would the all owners of the flats be able to chip in money to build a new apartment building?
- Also the same question if the building became too old (let's say after 20-30 years) and is uninhabitable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The land is divided into smaller parts and residents own the land in the same proportion their stake in the apartment building.

Comment: Do you have any sources that could back this up? I believe this is correct, but aren't there stipulations and don't land deeds have to be requested/acquired by the residents rather than just assumed to be given?

Comment: This answer is sheer hokum. Apartment buildings are usually run  by a landlord (not applicable here) or a housing society or condominium owners' association that collects dues from the owners and uses it to pay for the common expenses (lighting in the hallways, elevator maintenance and repair, janitorial services like vacuuming the hallways, etc., and it is this body that has title to the land. Of course, all the flat owners share in the ownership of the land but through the governing body, not individually.